# standard deviation decimal places?

Tags: java, linked-list

Could someone help me fiqure out why my decimals are wrong on the last line of output??

Here is my output:

> Sum of duration of Linkedlist: 3111480
>    Mean of LinkedList: 31114
>    SD of LinkedList: 9.65113011397E12
>
> Sum of time for Tree: 74628
>    Mean of Tree: 1184
>    SD of Tree: 5.486010029E9
>    Number of variables in Tree: 63
>
> Sum of time for HashSet: 33189
>    Mean of HashSet: 526
>    Std Dev of HashSet: 1.085445182E9
>    Number of variables in HashSet: 63
>
> The maximum sum of time for LinkedList(3111480),Tree(74628) and HashSet(33189) is 3111480
>
> The maximum mean of time for LinkedList(31114),Tree(1184) and HashSet(526) is 31114
>
> Maximum standard deviation for LinkedList(9651130113970.000000),  Tree(5486010029.00) and HashSet(1085445182.00) is 9651130113970.00 **line that is wrong**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class DataStructureTimingChris
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int MAXIMUM = 100;//initializing the maximum integer
int MINIMUM = 1;//initializing the minimum integer
int mean1 = 0;
int mean2 = 0;
int mean3 = 0;

//initializing the generation of random integers
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

//setting the range of integers from 1 to 1,000,000
int range = MAXIMUM - MINIMUM + 1;

//Array list for Hash Codes
ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbersHashCodes = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

//Array list for Storage
ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbersStorage = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

//for loop to generate 1,000,000 integers

for (int index = 1; index <= 100; ++index)
{
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(range) + MINIMUM;
  randomNumbersStorage.add(randomInt);
  randomNumbersHashCodes.add(String.valueOf(randomInt).hashCode());//storing randomly generated numbers in a ArrayList
}//end of for loop for random number generation and storage in an ArrayList


//array list to make string after converting int
ArrayList<String> randomNumbersStrg = new ArrayList<String>(randomNumbersHashCodes.size());

for (Integer myInt : randomNumbersHashCodes)

{
  randomNumbersStrg.add(String.valueOf(myInt));
}

//initializing LinkedList

List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

//adding generated hashcodes to Linked List

linkedList.addAll(randomNumbersStrg);

System.out.println();

List<Long> durations = new ArrayList<>(randomNumbersHashCodes.size());

for (int n : randomNumbersHashCodes)
{
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  randomNumbersHashCodes.contains(n); // true
  long end = System.nanoTime();
  durations.add(end - start);
}

//Initialize the tree
TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<String>();

//for loop for tree to add randomNumbersStrg to tree
for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
{
  tree.addAll(randomNumbersStrg);
}

//for loop to get times of tree
List<Long> durations2 = new ArrayList<>(tree.size());

for (String m : tree)

{
  long start2 = System.nanoTime();
  tree.contains(m); // true
  long end2 = System.nanoTime();
  durations2.add(end2 - start2);
}

//to calculate mean and SD of Durations 
int sum = 0;
double sd = 0;
for (int toCalcSum = 0; toCalcSum < durations.size(); toCalcSum++)
{
  sum += durations.get(toCalcSum);
}

for (int toCalcSD = 0; toCalcSD < durations.size(); toCalcSD++)
{
  sd += ((durations.get(toCalcSD) - sum) *
        (durations.get(toCalcSD) - sum)) / (durations.size() - 1);
}

mean1 = sum/durations.size();


//to print out the results of Linked List 
System.out.println("Sum of duration of Linkedlist: " + sum);
System.out.println("Mean of LinkedList: " + mean1);
System.out.println("SD of LinkedList: " + sd);
System.out.println();



//to calculate mean and SD of Durations2
int sum2 = 0;

double sd2 = 0;

for (int toCalcSum2 = 0; toCalcSum2 < durations2.size(); toCalcSum2++)

{
  sum2 += durations2.get(toCalcSum2); 
}

for (int toCalcSD2 = 0; toCalcSD2 < durations2.size(); toCalcSD2++)
{

  sd2 += ((durations2.get(toCalcSD2) - sum2) *
        (durations2.get(toCalcSD2) - sum2)) / 
        (durations2.size() - 1);
}

  mean2 = sum2/durations2.size();

    //to print out the results of Tree

  System.out.println("Sum of time for Tree: " + sum2);
  System.out.println("Mean of Tree: " + mean2);
  System.out.println("SD of Tree: " + sd2);
  System.out.println("# of variables in Tree: " + durations2.size());
  System.out.println();



 //to find Hashset
 HashSet<String> hash = new HashSet<>();

 for (int x = 1; x < randomNumbersStrg.size(); x++)

 {
    hash.addAll(randomNumbersStrg);
 }

  int sum3 = 0;
 double sd3 = 0;

 //for loop to get times of hash
 List<Long> durationsHashSet = new ArrayList<>(hash.size());

 for (String x : hash)
 {
     long start3 = System.nanoTime();
     hash.contains(x); // true
     long end3 = System.nanoTime();
     durationsHashSet.add(end3 - start3);
 }

 for (int toCalcSum3 = 0; toCalcSum3 < durationsHashSet.size(); toCalcSum3++)

 {
    sum3 += durationsHashSet.get(toCalcSum3);
 }

 for (int toCalcSD3 = 0; toCalcSD3 < durationsHashSet.size(); toCalcSD3++)

 {
    sd3 += ((durationsHashSet.get(toCalcSD3) - sum3) *
          (durationsHashSet.get(toCalcSD3) - sum3)) / (durationsHashSet.size() - 1);
 }

 mean3 = sum3 / durationsHashSet.size();

 //to print out the results of Hashset
 System.out.println("Sum of time for HashSet: " + sum3);
 System.out.println("Mean of HashSet: " + mean3);
 System.out.println("Std Dev of HashSet: " + sd3);
 System.out.println("Number of variables in HashSet: " + durationsHashSet.size());



 //to compare mean and standard Deviation
 System.out.println();
 System.out.printf("The maximum sum of time for LinkedList(%d),"
       + "Tree(%d) and HashSet(%d) is %d%n%n", sum, sum2, sum3,
       maximum(sum, sum2, sum3));
 System.out.printf("The maximum mean of time for LinkedList(%d),"
       + "Tree(%d) and HashSet(%d) is %d%n%n", mean1, mean2, mean3, 
       maximum(mean1, mean2, mean3));
 System.out.printf("Maximum standard deviation for LinkedList(%f), "
       + "Tree(%.2f) and HashSet(%.2f) is %.2f%n%n", sd, sd2, sd3, maximum(sd, sd2, sd3));



}// end of main method



public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T fromLinkedList, T fromTree, T fromHashSet)

{

  T max = fromLinkedList; // assume fromLinkedList is initially the largest

  if (fromTree.compareTo(max) > 0)

     max = fromTree; // fromTree is the largest so far

  if (fromHashSet.compareTo(max) > 0)

     max = fromHashSet; // fromHashSet is the largest

  return max; // returns the largest object

 }
 }//end of class
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I would STRONGLY recommend that you abstract out some of the common code into other methods. This will probably allow you to see the problem yourself

Comment: Furthermore, please specify your expected output. Some reformating of the observed output as well as the source code would help as well. Right now, it is very hard to extract the needed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract the mean (not the sum) when calculating each element's contribution to the variance - and then square root the variance to get the standard deviation.

For example:

```
mean1 = sum/durations.size();
double var = 0;
for (int toCalcSD = 0; toCalcSD < durations.size(); toCalcSD++)
{
  var += ((durations.get(toCalcSD) - mean1) *
         (durations.get(toCalcSD) - mean1)) / (durations.size() - 1);
}
sd = Math.sqrt(var);
```